# Имеет ли смысл оборачивать в объект код, написанный в функциональном стиле?

Tags: javascript

Под функциональным стилем я понимаю стиль, при котором просто комбинируется набор функций.

```
function a() {...}
function b() {...}
function c() {...}
```

Насколько я понимаю оборачивание такого кода в объект позволит избежать использования глобального объекта, что в теории может предотвратить какие либо конфликты.

```
var app = {
    a: function () {...},
    b: function () {...},
    c: function () {...}
};
```

Comment: Это зависит от целей которые вы пытаетесь достичь. первый вариант легче распределить по файлам.А так вы правы

Answer (score 0):

То что вы привели в примере называется модулем. В простейших случаях, как правило, используется паттерн Revealing Module:

```
var myModule = (function () {
    var privateVar = "", publicVar = "";

    function privateFunction() {
    }

    function publicSetter(val) {
        privateVar = val;
    }

    function publicGettter() {
        privateFunction();
    }

    return {
        mySetter: publicSetName,
        publicVariable: publicVar,
        myGetter: publicGetter
    };
})();
```

Comment: а зачем переменную создавать? myModule

Comment: это же все в замыкании остается, без переменной доступа к объекту не будет

Comment: myModule это не ссылка на объект, а вообще про какой объект речь идет не понимаю?)

Comment: в myModule будет как раз объект, в приведенном коде функция сразу же исполняется (запись вида (function(){})() aka IIFE) и возвращает объект в return

Comment: зачем целый объект создавать?

Comment: @MikhailM Вы написали про модуль: http://largescalejs.ru/module-pattern/, а я написал про литеральную нотацию объектов: http://largescalejs.ru/object-literal-notation/. По сути одно и тоже, только к свойствам объекта можно получить доступ извне (хотя по-моему ничего не мешает спрятать всё что надо в методы этого объекта). Плюс обращение к свойствам объекта `app.p` исключает вероятность того, что подхватятся какие либо переменные из внешней области видимости (хотя это уже придирки).

Comment: @АлександрПиткевич он возвращает объект чтобы потом можно было красиво обращаться к свойствам модуля `myModule.mySetter`, а всё что в этот возвращаемый объект не включено остаётся скрытым внутри замыкания.

Comment: @Khipster так а разве суть модуля не в том, чтобы создать локальною область видимости для функций и в дальнейшем избегать конфликтов с глобальной областью видимости?

Comment: @АлександрПиткевич Суть модуля в том чтобы его куда то подключить, не разбираясь что там у него внутри. Так вот чтобы его куда то подключить и нужен интерфейс работы с модулем - а это как раз и есть возвращаемый объект со свойствами и методами `myModule.mySetter` и тд. Залезть в модуль снаружи и испортить его нельзя, но вот из модуля можно испортить глобальный объект, поэтому надо аккуратно писать сам модуль.

Comment: @Khipster окей) спорить не буду, пока что не очень силен в модулях, поэтому приму на веру)